# x11vnc error: "The program "Xvfb" could not be found."

Tags: mac, vnc, x11

Lately I've been accessing an Ubuntu machine over the internet. I'd been connecting and starting an x11vnc server using the following command

```
ssh me@my.computer -p 2222  -L 5903:localhost:5900 "x11vnc -display :0 -noxdamage - create -usepw -once"
```

and then I'd open `localhost:5903` in my MacBook's native screen sharing program.

This had all been working fine for several days, until just now, after I upgraded Ubuntu. Now the command fails with the following error:

```
The program "Xvfb" could not be found in PATH and standard locations.
You probably need to install a package that provides the "Xvfb" program.
Without it FINDCREATEDISPLAY mode may not be able to create an X display.

25/05/2012 15:53:39 wait_for_client: find display cmd failed.
25/05/2012 15:53:39 wait_for_client: FINDCREATEDISPLAY cmd: /bin/sh /tmp/x11vnc-find_display.jXgwux Xvfb
trying N=20 ...

The program "Xvfb" could not be found in PATH and standard locations.
You probably need to install a package that provides the "Xvfb" program.

25/05/2012 15:53:39 wait_for_client: read failed: /bin/sh /tmp/x11vnc-find_display.jXgwux Xvfb
25/05/2012 15:53:39 fgets: Bad file descriptor
```

Does anyone know what's happened and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you try to install the virtual framebuffer package xvfb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install `xvfb` with `sudo apt-get install xvfb -y` in a terminal. Xvfb -- "X Virtual FrameBuffer" emulates/"fakes" an X disPlay when there is no physical display connected to the system. A common use for it is to run programs which require a display on headless systems.

Comment: Right. That solved one problem, but now I have another: When I connect with VNC I can only see a command line interface, not the full Graphical Desktop. Any idea how to fix **that**?

Comment: Does the problem have something to do with the -create flag I'm using with x11vnc?